# How to define mongoose _id in TypeScript interface?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and TypeScript with the interface+[class](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html#creating-from-es6-classes-using-loadclass)+schema [approach](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose#static-methods).

*What is the canonical way to store the `_id` field?*

I know the db stores it as a bson `ObjectID`. But I've seen some examples using `string` and others using mongoose's `ObjectId`, and then converting between them for various reasons - so I'm unsure which to use.

```
interface Animal {
  _id: ?type?;        // ?
  name: string;
}
```

Is it advisable to use

- `string`
- `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`
- `mongodb.ObjectID`
- `bson.ObjectID`

Also, assuming it is correct to use objectid - I want to avoid taking a dependency on mongoose in the interface file. Is it safe/advisable to use the `bson` package's `ObjectID` instead - are they equivalent?

Answer (score 23):

you can do this

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';
interface Animal {
  _id: Types.ObjectId,      
  name: string
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, ObjectId refers to Schema.Types.ObjectId, you want `import {Types} from 'mongoose'; _id: Types.Object`.

Answer (score 11):

Taken from the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html):

- Import `Types` from mongoose
- Use this type for your `_id`

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose';

interface Animal {
  _id: Types.ObjectId;
  name: string;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: 4 years later and mongoose claims this approach will be dropped for performance reasons in it's next release.  See docs link in comments.

You can extend your interface with `mongoose.Document`. Your interface will be come

```
interface Animal extends mongoose.Document { 
  name: string;
}
```

Usage:

```
export let AnimalSchema = mongoose.model<Animal>('animal', schema, 'animals');
let animal = await AnimalSchema.find({_id: "id"}).exec();
// animal._id / animal.name
```

Comment: I do it [another way](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/mongoose#static-methods) to keep my entity files clean of infrastructure dependencies. Also, what about the original issue - what type is best to use?

Comment: aww, I think `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` is good for you case, `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` has been defined by `typeof mongodb.ObjectID & {
      (s?: string | number): mongodb.ObjectID;
    };`

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#using-extends-document - *We **strongly** recommend against using this approach, its support will be dropped in the next major version as it causes major performance issues. Many Mongoose TypeScript codebases use the below approach.*